# Javascript item selector

Tags: javascript, filter, selector

I'm trying to create a kind of item selector using JavaScript. The selector would be similar to the setup below:

```
<label>Stone</label>
<select id="stone">
  <option value="aquamarine">Aquamarine</option>
  <option value="pink-topaz">Pink Topaz</option>
  <option value="tourmaline">Tourmaline</option>
</select>
<label>Metal</label>
<select id="metal">
  <option value="silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="white-gold">White Gold</option>
  <option value="yellow-gold">Yellow Gold</option>
  <option value="rose-gold">Rose Gold</option>
</select>
```

With an image container like so:

```
<img src="path/to/image/silver_aquamarine.jpg" id="imageToSwap">
```

And the JavaScript as follows:

```
$('#stone, #metal').on('change', function() {
  $('#imageToSwap').prop('src', ['path/to/image/', $('#metal').val(), '_',     $('#stone').val(), '.jpg'].join('')    
  );
});
```

And all that is working just fine. What I'm wondering is (and apologies in advance for having NO idea how to approach this) is there a way pull in other values that are associated with the image. For example, can I bring in the price associated with that selection?

Or, should I be approaching this in an entirely different way? Maybe an array of items, each with an image, price, stone and metal, that are shown based on the selection but using something similar to a filter?

Also, I'll need to create a fallback for what happens if the option doesn't exist. Let's say all combinations exist except for Aquamarine + Rose Gold. How could I add a message saying "option doesn't exist"?

Any help here would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up an object. That looks like:

```
var details = {
    stone: {
        aquamarine: 100, // the price is 100 dollars
        "pink-topaz": 75, // the price is 75 dollars
        tourmaline:  88 // and so on
    },
    metal: {
        silver: 140,
        platinum: 250,
        "white-gold": 400,
        "yellow-gold": 390,
        "rose-gold": 420
    }
}
$('#stone, #metal').on('change', function() {
  var metal = $('#metal').val();
  var stone = $('#stone').val();
  var price = details.metal[metal] + details.stone[stone];

  // there is no need in using an array and joining it.
  var src = 'path/to/image/' + metal + '_' + stone + ".jpg";
  $(".details").remove();
  $('#imageToSwap').prop('src', src);
  $("#metal").after('<span class="details"><br/>The price of this image is ' + price + "</span>");
});
```

See it working: http://jsfiddle.net/FLTJR/

The only thing you will need to figure out is the price algorithm.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. The image has stopped swapping when the selection is changed. To answer your question, I'd like to show the price below the image in a paragraph.

Comment: @blicht454 I fixed the code. And it should add the price after the image now.

Comment: Much closer. The only problem is, if I change the selectors more than once, the price is echoed out over and over, like this: The price of this image is 478The price of this image is 465The price of this image is 475The price of this image is 215. Also, what if I want the price to echo somewhere below the dropdowns instead of attached to the image?

Comment: You can put it wherever you need it.

Comment: @blicht454 It all about what element you attach `.after('<span class="details"><br/>The price of this image is ' + price + "</span>")` too. And btw, I fixed the issue with the multiple echo's. I also changed the position of the message so that it is below the dropdowns: http://jsfiddle.net/FLTJR/2/

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for your help! Just one last question: if all of the images for all products are uploaded to the same folder, can I add a third variable for something like "item". That way, if more than one item has an image with the same metal and stone, the selection will pull up the proper image.

Comment: @blicht454 I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean like having the url look like: `path/to/image/silver_aquamarine_item1.jpg`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That way the images will be specific to that item even if their metal & stone overlap with another item.

Comment: @blicht454 Wouldn't it just be okay to use `path/to/image/silver_aquamarine.jpg` multiple times? How exactly do you want to determine the item number?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the prices of your items then you could use [data-attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to attach them to your options and then access them using jQuery. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PM6qu/

```
<label>Stone</label>
<select id="stone">
  <option value="aquamarine"  data-stone-price = "2">Aquamarine</option>
  <option value="pink-topaz"  data-stone-price = "3">Pink Topaz</option>
  <option value="tourmaline"  data-stone-price = "4">Tourmaline</option>
</select>
<label>Metal</label>
<select id="metal">
  <option value="silver" data-metal-price = "2">Silver</option>
  <option value="platinum" data-metal-price = "4">Platinum</option>
  <option value="white-gold" data-metal-price = "3">White Gold</option>
  <option value="yellow-gold" data-metal-price = "3">Yellow Gold</option>
  <option value="rose-gold" data-metal-price = "3">Rose Gold</option>
</select>

<img src="path/to/image/silver_aquamarine.jpg" id="imageToSwap">
<div id="price"></div>
```

Accessing data atributes:

```
$('#stone, #metal').on('change', function() {
  $('#imageToSwap').prop('src', ['path/to/image/', $('#metal').val(), '_',     $('#stone').val(), '.jpg'].join('')    
  );
    alert($('#stone option:selected').data('stone-price') + $('#metal option:selected').data('metal-price'));
});
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to approach it, but the pricing won't necessarily be as simple as Stone price + Metal price.

Comment: Of course. My intent was to offer you an alternative way to send data on to client and access it there. If you could stress more on how the pricing would work then perhaps we can build on this.